# C Socket crash on iPhone device. EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: c, ios, sockets, exc-bad-access

I have code that runs well on the simulator but as soon as I try it on the device the program is crashing.

It happens when initializing the socket.. here is my code and what run/debug spits out. (SERVER_NAME is the hostname of my machine where the server is running)

Error:

```
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
warning: Unable to read symbols for /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/4.3.3 (8J3)/Symbols/Developer/usr/lib/libXcodeDebuggerSupport.dylib (file not found).
```

in .h

```
    int connectionSocket;
struct hostent *server;
struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
```

in .m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

TRANSFER_COMPLETED = false;
TIME_COMPLETED = false;

//[UIApplication sharedApplication].idleTimerDisabled = YES;    //Disable app sleep (check this out)


//Build connection to Server
portNumber = PORT_NUM;
connectionSocket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME);
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);   
//server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)server->h_addr);   
memcpy ( &( server_addr.sin_addr ), server->h_addr, server->h_length );

if (connect(connectionSocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) == -1) 
{
    perror("Connect");
    exit(1);
}   

//Setup Battery monitoring and Device characteristics
myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
myDevice.batteryMonitoringEnabled = YES;
NSString* sysName = myDevice.systemName;
NSString* sysVersion = myDevice.systemVersion;

//Name the file for this device

NSString* myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"systemName:%@ systemVersion:%@ \n", sysName, sysVersion];

const char* deviceInfo = malloc(128);
char* deviceSettings = malloc(256);

deviceInfo = [myString UTF8String];

//Get the battery State
int intBatteryState = myDevice.batteryState;
char* batteryState = malloc(24);
switch(intBatteryState){
    case 0: 
        batteryState = "Unknown";
        break;
    case 1:
        batteryState = "Unplugged";
        break;
    case 2:
        batteryState = "Charging";
        break;
    case 3:
        batteryState = "plugged and full";
        break;
    default:
        batteryState = "Error";
        break;
}   

sprintf(deviceSettings, "iOS Test *** APPLICATION_BUFFER_SIZE(B): %i, SLEEP_TIME(microseconds) per app buffer size: %i, TOTAL_BYTES_EXPECTED per download: %i, TOTAL_DOWNLOADS: %i, TEST_TIME(s): %i, Battery State:%s \n", (int) round(APPLICAION_BUFFER_SIZE), SLEEP_TIME, TOTAL_BYTES_EXPECTED, TOTAL_DOWNLOADS, TEST_TIME, batteryState);

send(connectionSocket, DEVICE_NAME, strlen(DEVICE_NAME), 0);
sleep(1);
send(connectionSocket, deviceSettings, strlen(deviceSettings), 0);
send(connectionSocket, deviceInfo, strlen(deviceInfo), 0);

free(deviceSettings);
//free(deviceInfo);//Says it is being freed without being allocated but I allocated it with malloc...
//free(batteryState); 

//  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(download) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

//  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(keepRunning) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
//  [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(busyLoop) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
//

```
//  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryLevelDidChange) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

//  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryStateDidChange) name:UIDeviceBatteryStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];

Comment: Just a suggestion: `server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME);` is deprecated. Its nice to look at [getaddrinfo()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#getaddrinfoman)

Comment: Whats the output of `server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
memcpy ( &( serv_addr.sin_addr ), server->h_addr, server->h_length );
```

in place of

```
server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)server->h_addr);
```

OR you can use `server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);`

This is just to avoid crash. But I'm not sure why `server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)server->h_addr);` will crash.

EDIT:
Try this:

```
portNumber = PORT_NUM;
connectionSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;     
server_addr.sin_port = htons(portNumber);   
server_addr.sin_addr.saddr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

This does not require `server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME);`

One more thing that I noted is:

```
connectionSocket = socket(**PF_INET**, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
//server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME);
server_addr.sin_family = **AF_INET**;
```

Is this alright. I mean different protocols in two statements?

Comment: @Mayank thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Michael: I understand that both statements are similar... Could you please add some more code... Like if you are checking for NULL before coming inside.

Comment: I did a similar mistake once. In that case I was checking `if (NULL == server)` but server was uninitialized, not set to NULL. I hope such things are already being handled

Comment: Hm, to be honest I am digging back into C after several years away so I may be missing some important steps... I have updated the code to include the entire viewdidload function from the .m and I commented out all calls to other local functions to be sure the problem was in that code block.  When I said your suggestion didn't change anything I meant the program performed the same... not your code was the same - I did not mean for it to come off in that way.

Comment: @Michael: That's fine. Even I did not look into C sockets for a long time. Well, we need to figure out what's going on here. Could you please check the output of `server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME);`

Comment: @Mayank it looks like you are onto something. (server == NULL) is true. This must mean I need to malloc it rather than just declare it in the header?

Comment: No, if output of `server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME);` is NULL that means C library is does not understand SERVER_NAME. Had it been on IP network I could request you to test on IP of the system. I don't know if iPhone provides an IP

Comment: Messing with `sin_addr` and such is always wrong. You should never create sockaddr_* structures yourself or use `gethostbyname`. Always use `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo` only.

Comment: Just a suggestion: server = gethostbyname(SERVER_NAME); is deprecated. Its nice to look at [getaddrinfo()](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/singlepage/bgnet.html#getaddrinfoman)

Comment: @Mayank that is not good... It is weird how it would work on the simulator but not on a device.

Comment: @Mayank @R.. thanks for tip, I will see what getaddrinfo() is all about.

Comment: @Michael: I have no idea, as I've never worked on mobile devices. But this is quite an interesting case and can be put as a new question in SO, once this issue is resolved. Well, if SERVER_NAME and IP approaches do not work onw last try may be `server_addr.sin_addr.saddr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);`. If this works, test your business case. Once things are okay change your code to incorporate `getaddrinfo` as suggested by @R

Comment: @Mayank Ok, I haven't had any luck yet but I am basically using the code from the link you suggested but it doesn't like my nodename it says "getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known" I've tried my IP and my hostname in nodename and I've got the servname as "11313" I will need to keep digging into it.

Comment: Strange ... 11313 is your port num too :-)

Comment: @Mayank I think that is how it is supposed to work. with the IP in the servname. At this point I am basically just trying to hack something together :). Anything that works would be amazing.

Comment: Did you try `server_addr.sin_addr.saddr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);` Try once when you find time :-)

Comment: Yeah, I made sure to try all your ideas. The gethostbyname() still outputs NULL, so I need to address that first.

Comment: I appreciate all your help by the way... I tried to one up your post but I guess my rep is too low.

Comment: Step in the right direction.. The program no longer crashes but the socket doesn't communicate with the server.

Comment: Can it connect... Have a look here may help http://lists.apple.com/archives/darwin-development/2002/May/msg00410.html